# JQuery: How to go through all the characters and change each letters colours for different DIV

Tags: jquery, css, colors

I'm trying to modify the code on this page: [jQuery: How to go through all the characters in <p> paragraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867594/jquery-how-to-go-through-all-the-characters-in-p-paragraph)

...but to use on different DIVs:

```
var $p = $('.couleurs');

var array = $p.text().split('');

var colors = ['bleu','orange','vert','rose','rouge'];

$.each(array, function( i ) {
array[i] = '<span class="' + colors[ i % 5 ] + '">' + array[i] + '</span>';
});

$p.html(array.join(''));
```

My problem now is that if I use the class ".couleurs" on different DIVs, the text from previous divs with this class is added. Like this:

```
<div class="couleurs">Some text</div>
<div class="couleurs">More text</div>
```

...will display this:

> Some textMore text

Anyone can help?

Comment: The linked answer also only worked on a single paragraph. YOu'd have to use .each to iterate over each one separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with each `div` separately. For example (variation of your code):

```
var colors = ['bleu', 'orange', 'vert', 'rose', 'rouge'];

$('.couleurs').html(function() {
    return $.map($(this).text().split(''), function(el, i) {
        return '<span class="' + colors[i % 5] + '">' + el + '</span>';
    }).join('');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/22eED/

Internally jQuery uses `each` to loop over set of matched divs.

Comment: +1 this is the beautiful and advanced way of achieving the same - first maybe he should try to understand how `each()` works :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the whole thing in an [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) so it runs separately for all paragraphs. The problem with your code is that it tries to work on all paragraphs at once.

```
var $p = $('.couleurs');
var colors = ['bleu','orange','vert','rose','rouge'];

$p.each(function () {
    var array = $(this).text().split('');

    $.each(array, function( i ) {
        array[i] = '<span class="' + colors[ i % 5 ] + '">' + array[i] + '</span>';
    });

    $(this).html(array.join(''));
});
```

[A little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zq6X5/)

Comment: I agree, that using `each` is a little more explicit and comprehensive.